# Add check_mark to Edit | undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, checkbox, undefined, edit

In **edit.html.erb** I tried

`<%= @routine.check_box :archive %>`, which caused: `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method 'check_box' for #<Routine:0x007f836fe69de0>):`

I then tried in edit:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@routine) do |f| %> 
 <%= f.check_box :archive %>
<% end %>
```

That removed the error, but when I clicked on the checkbox it wouldn't update to true.

**schema**

```
t.boolean  "archive",          default: false
```

**routines_controller**

```
def edit
end

def update
  respond_modal_with @routine, location: root_path
end

def routine_params
  params.require(:routine).permit(
  :archive,)
end
```

Comment: Are you sure, you ran the `rake db:migrate` ? or please check in your rails console if the field is present in the model or not..

Comment: Yes @ArupRakshit I ran `rake db:migrate` and I checked the console. The field is still false even after check marking it.

Comment: What happens when you add `:id` to the `params.require(:routine).permit(
  :archive, :id)`?

Comment: @Pavan never add `:id` .. it is DB thing. We update other attributes except `id`. `id` we will get from URL .. this is how we/I do. :) but `id` shouldn't be in the strong params list

Comment: @ArupRakshit Yeah! Just confused :D

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `boolean` helper. Look [Available input types](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#available-input-types-and-defaults-for-each-column-type) list.

```
<%= simple_form_for(@routine) do |f| %> 
 <%= f.input :archive, as: :boolean, checked_value: true, unchecked_value: false %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Nope. `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method 'boolean'` but thanks for trying Arup!

Comment: Do I need `<%= simple_form_for(@routine) do |f| %> ` in edit.html.erb? I don't have that line in my other edit forms? Just curious

Comment: where you keep the code, doesn't matter until you have access to the object.. But I am not getting why it is throwing error.. But you need to have `@routine = Routine.find(some_id)`, but I hope you have that... Otherwise, we could get some other error

Comment: This is wrong man. There is no such helper called `boolean` for `form_for`.

Comment: @Pavan look the table https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#available-input-types-and-defaults-for-each-column-type .. And the issue with OP something else.

Comment: @Pavan Yes true.. :p

Comment: Those are the datatypes. Those are not form_helpers. Check the available form helpers here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

Comment: @Pavan still that table for simple_for options.. Because you see `hidden` in the table, which is not also a data type.. it is the options the Gem used. But anyway thanks for the pointer.. I misread it.

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com Please try now.. and make me happy :D

Comment: Now your answer is correct. The issue with OP could be he is using `form_for` helpers for `simple_form_for` :)

Comment: Still didn't switch to true after I clicked on the checkbox, `archive: false`. I have no idea why this doesn't work. For example, `<%= f.check_box :archive %>` works if I put it in _form, but not directly in edit.html.erb.